# AWS MSK lambda concurrent consumers

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-msk

AWS Lambda Supports Parallelization Factor for Kinesis and DynamoDB Event Sources. But its not supported for MSK. Can we create a reserved concurrency of the Lambda function and would it help to concurrently consume from MSK topic

Answer (score 1):

TL'DR Connecting lambda to kafka cluster using aws::event-source-mapping is limited to the amount of partitions you are having in the topics

I had the experience to setup a poc of

```
Custom Kafka Cluster Topic (1 Partition) > EventSourceMapping > Lambda
```

and after opening a discussion with AWS it looks like it is a limitation

Another approach that I didn't try is to setup a lambda sink (kafka connect) and setup a `tasks.max` which seems like it can solve this issue
https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/aws-lambda/current/overview.html#lambda-sink-multiple-tasks

Comment: but can we force a lambda to run 1 consumer per partition instead of sometimes running one consumer form many partitions and, thus, having a lower throughtput?

Comment: @pbsb Good question. How do you configure the lambda to spin up a new instance for each topic partition? Mine is just spinning up one consumer for the whole topic (6 partitions)

Comment: too late but if you are here then i found that more partitions increase the number of parallel execution. But if you add partition to topic after connecting it to lambda, it wont consider new partitions. So remove event mapping from lambda > add more partitions to topic > re add the event mapping to the topic. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

The specifics in documentation is pretty sparse. I also was looking for this, the only thing I've found is from this:
https://amazonmsk-labs.workshop.aws/en/msklambda/tpschemareg/overview.html

In it they read from MSK and post to Kinesis so that lambda can process in parallel. It seems like the MSK event source is there mainly for migration if true. Only one consumer is pretty limiting.

Maybe someone who experimented more can leave a better answer.

krishwin's comment at the bottom of this article also seems to indicate this.
https://dev.to/danieljameskay/triggering-lambda-functions-from-amazon-msk-316o

A better option might be a AWS lambda sink connector. It looks like it will run a lambda process up to number of partitions:

- https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-aws-lambda/current/index.html
- https://github.com/Nordstrom/kafka-connect-lambda
- https://github.com/llofberg/kafka-connect-aws-lambda
- https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/latest/connectors/camel-aws2-lambda-kafka-sink-connector.html

Answer (score -1):

You can set `ParallelApplyThreads` as more than 1 in the `TargetMetadata` on the task settings.

Check [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TaskSettings.TargetMetadata.html) document.

Answer (score -1):

Lambda has auto scaling to control the concurrency. You usually do not need set the concurrency unless you have specific need.
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/01/aws-lambda-auto-scaling-msk-apache-kafka/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).